# Elegant way to take basename of directory in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, directory-structure

I have several scripts that take as input a directory name, and my program creates files in those directories. Sometimes I want to take the basename of a directory given to the program and use it to make various files in the directory.  For example,

```
# directory name given by user via command-line
output_dir = "..." # obtained by OptParser, for example
my_filename = output_dir + '/' + os.path.basename(output_dir) + '.my_program_output'
# write stuff to my_filename
```

The problem is that if the user gives a directory name with a trailing slash, then os.path.basename will return the empty string, which is not what I want. What is the most elegant way to deal with these slash/trailing slash issues in python? I know I can manually check for the slash at the end of output_dir and remove it if it's there, but there seems like there should be a better way.  Is there?

Also, is it OK to manually add '/' characters?  E.g. output_dir + '/' os.path.basename() or is there a more generic way to build up paths?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To deal with your "trailing slash" issue (and other issues!), sanitise user input with `os.path.normpath()`.

To build paths, use `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build up paths.  For example:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> path = 'foo/bar'
>>> os.path.join(path, 'filename')
'foo/bar/filename'
>>> path = 'foo/bar/'
>>> os.path.join(path, 'filename')
'foo/bar/filename'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to add paths together.

use

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.join(output_dir,''))
```

to extract dirname, while adding a trailing slash if it was omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Manually building up paths is a bad idea for portability; it will break on Windows. You should use os.path.sep.

As for your first question, using os.path.join is the right idea.

Comment: """it will break on Windows""": Including slashes will break only if you feed it as part of a command to e.g. `os.system()`; the DOS command parser understands only backslashes. Feeding it to e.g. open() is quite OK. However if the constructed path is ever to be displayed to a Windows user or admin, be prepared for a lot of flak :-)

Answer (score 1):

to build the paths without writing slashes it is better to use:

```
os.path.join(dir, subdir, file)
```

if you want to add separators or get the separator independly of the os, then use

```
 os.sep
```

Comment: as OP stated, the problem is that if d is "mydir" then this would return an empty string.

Comment: @Ofri: the corresponding section has been eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pathlib library, works everytime

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> print(Path("/sample/path/).name)
path
>>> print(Path("/sample/path).name)
path
```