# path.basename applied to directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

Here is what Node.js does:

```
path.basename("/var/") === "var"
path.parse("/var/") === {root: "/", dir: "/", base: "var", name: "var", ext: ""}
```

And here is what I would expect:

```
path.basename("/var/") === ""
path.parse("/var/") === {root: "/", dir: "/var/", base: "", name: "", ext: ""}
```

My assumption is that this isn't a bug because if it were, it'd likely break so many Node.js modules that it'd be a full-on crisis. Instead, does anyone know the reasoning for this behavior? It seems completely counter-intuitive to me, and tests with similar libraries in other languages show the behavior I expected.

Comment: A directory is a lot like a file. `/var/` is a path to a directory. `"var"` is the name of the directory. Voilà.

Comment: Sure, but it still stands that this isn't how path parsing normally works right?

Comment: Normally how? `basename /var/` is `var`.

Comment: ```import os.path as osp; osp.basename("/var/")``` returns "" in Python

Comment: To be clear, it's stupid easy to get around this for my own purposes. I just don't understand why the Node developers decided to do things this way, which afaict is less useful than the behavior I expected.

Comment: See the note at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename and compare `from pathlib import Path; Path("/var/").name == "var"`. Sure, maybe your particular application wants different behaviour; [others don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663512/elegant-way-to-take-basename-of-directory-in-python). I think being in line with basename(1) makes sense.

Comment: Ah, that'd do it then. Nevermind anything I think, basename(1) should definitely get precedent.